# Is there any printing error here in this code? (python)

Tags: python

I basically have created a program in python to get the largest number by accepting two numbers.
This works fine. But if you try to enter 12 as first number and 4 as a second number, then I don't know what kind of logic error is going on!!

**Code:**

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
num2 = input("Enter one more number: ")

print(num1,num2)

if num1 > num2:
    print(num1, "is greater than", num2)
elif num2 > num1:
    print(num2, "is greater than", num1)
else:
    print("Both the numbers are equal!")
```

Comment: You are comparing num1 and num2 as a string, 
convert them to int using -> `int(input("Enter number"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings, as `input()` returns `str`

Change the type to `int` then compare

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter one more number: "))

print(num1,num2)

if num1 > num2:
    print(num1, "is greater than", num2)
elif num2 > num1:
    print(num2, "is greater than", num1)
else:
    print("Both the numbers are equal!")
```

what you are doing

for eg: if numbers are `321` and `1234`

It won't give an error. But `"321">"1234"` will be considered as `True`which is in-correct

Comment: It won't give an error that is correct. But `"321">"1234"` will be considered as `True` which is in-correct

Answer (score 1):

**Python takes input as String**

Convert your String input into Integer

Just make these 2 changes in starting 2 lines :

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter one more number: "))
```